# Decompiling very heavily obfuscated JAR

Tags: decompilation, deobfuscation

I have a very *very* obfuscated jar. I tried using Krakatau and CFR and it won't decompile. With CFR some of the important classes / methods fail to decompile and with krak it says it is writing data to the zip but nothing actually is generated. The jar in this case is a mod which I know contains code that sends personal information (e.g. your chrome passwords, minecraft account, discord information, etc.) to a webhook. I tried seeing the code I managed to decompile but all I found was a remote toggle, a SQL driver and a query to discordapp (not a post). Does anyone have any thoughts on what I could do to find and nuke the discord webhook?
The mod is [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/41zrli19ij3w055/KuudraHelper-1.2.jar/file).

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find the webhook by using Recaf and generating mappings then just doing some browsing

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. Unfortunately this "answer" won't help anyone. We _do_ appreciate answering own questions. But this contains no information other than that you found some answers. Would you care to share your findings? As it stands your "answer" may even get removed, since it isn't an _answer_.

Comment: Hi, I don't really know what to add, There is no point adding the URL that I found and all I really wanted to say is that to someone in a simliar situation, just using Recaf to make mappings and reading through the code should be enough.